# tsconfig.json set error - does it matter?

Tags: typescript

I have set my tsconfig.json file up in the folder containing my ts files. I generated it in vsCode initially with tsc --init, but it came with the lib es5, and when I tried to compile my ts file, gave me the error:

error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

So I updated it to es2015. Now I've restarted VSCode, re-opened the terminal, and still it says the same thing. Google turns up plenty of references to the error, but they all seem to be either fixed-bug or one of the above (refresh, re-open). The compile seemed to go through (I now have a reasonable looking .js file), but the error still worries me. Is this something I can ignore, or is there some other way to update the tsconfig so that VSCode is aware of the changes? I'm new to VSCode as well, so it wouldn't surprise me if there's some sort of rebuild I need to do.

From the tsconfig.json file:

```
...{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                         /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es2015",                                
    "module": "commonjs",                           
    "lib": ["es2015"],
```

In case it could effect this, I did install with npm twice because I forgot the global flag the first time: npm i -D typescript and then npm install -g typescript.